# Path independence and Spherically Symmetric Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, conservative-field

---

This problem is from John Taylor's *Classical Mechanics*.

[image: Problem From John Taylor's Book]

---

I can't figure out how to prove that a series of paths consisting of paths moving radially or in the angular direction. I understand intuitively that it works, but I'm not sure if I know to prove that the series of paths converges to an arbitrary path. My first thought was to segment an arbitrary path $R=R(t)$ from $A=R(0)$ to $B=R(1)$ into $N$ pieces and construct a "*spherical*" sequence of paths $P=\{AP_2=P_1P_2,\dots,P_{M-1}P_M=P_{M-1}B\}$ such that each path is either stricly radial, or strictly angular (in the $\varphi$ or $\theta$ directions) and each point $R(\frac{i}{N})$ is intersected by some path $P_jP_{(j+1)}$ in $P$. Then using the definition of spherical symmetry,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}\int_{i/M}^{(i+1)/M}f(r)\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}W_{P_iP_{(i+1)}}\\
=W_{AP_2}+\cdots+W_{P_{M-1}B}
$$
where $W_{P_iP_{i+1}}=0$ if the path $P_iP_{i+1}$ is a movement in an angular direction.
How can I show that this is a reasonable approximation?

Comment: I'm a little surprised to see this has attracted close votes on the grounds that it is a homework or check my work question. This seems a perfectly good question to me.

Comment: @JohnRennie Not a homework question. I am self taught (mostly), so books and the internet are my teachers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path went from A to B in a series of small steps like this

[image]

If we focus on one of the steps, the real path in blue can be approximated as a straight line

[image]

the work done, against $F$, going from P to R, is $PR\times Fcos\theta$ and this is the same as $F\times PQ$. Since it's true for one of the small steps it'll be true for the whole path

Comment: Much simpler than my argument. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, all the best.